# Getting the "sibling" of a "child" in xml.etree.ElementTree, Python,

Tags: python, elementtree

I am new to XML and python, I am struggling to get the "sibling" of a "child"

I have this XML

```
<notes>
    <Def id="1"> 
        <module>DDAC</module>
        <tags> lalala</tags>
        <description> John and Mark are good friends. </description>
    </Def>
    <Def id="2"> 
        <module>FYP</module>
        <tags> lelele</tags>
        <description> John works in Google. </description>
    </Def>
    <Def id="3"> 
        <module>FYP</module>
        <tags> lilili</tags>
        <description> Mark work in IBM. </description>
    </Def>
    <Def id="4"> 
        <module>DDAC</module>
        <tags> lololo</tags>
        <description> A computer can help you do stuff </description>
    </Def>
    <Def id="5"> 
        <module>IMNPD</module>
        <tags> lululu</tags>
        <description> The internet is a world wide web </description>
    </Def>
</notes>
```

I want to get the description for all the module "DDAC"

```
for g in root.iter('module'):
    if g.text == 'DDAC':
        x = root.iter("description")
        print(x)
```

my desire output is:

> > John and Mark are good friends.
> >
> > A computer can help you do stuff

but I am getting the object not the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your xml data is in a file called test.xml, the following code should work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()
for Def in root.findall('Def'):
    module = Def.find('module').text
    if module == 'DDAC':
        print(Def.find('description').text)
```

Comment: @haraprasadj nice! but how can I get to where I want if the tree has hundreds of levels?

Comment: @Heinz there is no need to iterate from top element. Also you can use an xpath like  - els = root.findall(".//*[module='DDAC']/description") - and get the text of all elements. Here we are looking for the description of all elements whose module is DDAC.